# Find barcode type on scan for Honeywell Captuvo device

Tags: ios, swift, barcode-scanner, honeywell

I am using Honeywell Captuvo Device and it's SDK for scanning barcode with iPod. Unfortunately there is **no delegate methods** which can give a **Type of Barcode Scanned**. There are two delegate method which gives you string value of barcode and NSData from the barcode scanned.

```
//Raw Data by delegate method. 
func decoderRawDataReceived(data: NSData!) {

}

//String return by delegate method.
func decoderDataReceived(data: String!) {

}
```

As i am getting two type of data from scanning a barcode. I have been searching for a solution by which i can get barcode type of scanned data.

Is there a way i can get Barcode type from NSData or String type?

Comment: Not unless the `NSString` or `NSData` somehow encodes that information. You'd have to look at the SDK docs to see if that's the case.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not the case. Incase if you would like to look at SDK information you can find the SDK [here](https://github.com/BlueFletch/cordova-plugin-honeywell-captuvo)

Comment: No thank you. Out of curiosity, why does it matter what kind of bar code it is? With bar codes, the string and/or binary value is usually all that matter.

Comment: Different kind of barcode will be scanned in my project. Based on the barcode type i have to make a query in database. As purpose of all barcode kind will be different.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an answer to this as well, and came up with a roundabout way to do it since the SDK doesn't have that ability.

In the Captuvo Sled User's Guide, it outlines ways to configure the scanner separately from the SDK. In the Data Editing section, it outlines some configuration options that you may be interested in. You can add a prefix/suffix to different barcode symbologies.

Perhaps easier, is, in the Data Formatting section, it mentions the ability to:

> ## Insert symbology name
>
> #### B3
>
> Insert the name of the bar code’s symbology in the output message,
> without moving the cursor. Only symbologies with a Honeywell ID are
> included (see Symbology Chart on page A-1). Refer to the ASCII
> Conversion Chart (Code Page 1252), page A-4 for decimal, hex and
> character codes.

So, configure the scanner first, and then you'll be able to parse the
symbology.

Comment: Thanks Zig. How do i configure the scanner? were you able to get barcode type?